# Javascript simple code error for beginner

Tags: javascript

I don't know why, but my code always get an error:

> Oops, try again. It looks like your function doesn't return "Get some
>   more shut eye!" when numHours is 5. Check your if / else syntax and
>   whether you're using the correct comparison operator.

I hope some help, thank so much for your answer!

```
var sleepCheck = function(numHours){
if (numHours >= 8) {
return "You're getting plenty of sleep! Maybe even too much!";
} else {
return "Get more some shut eye!";
}
};

sleepCheck(10);
sleepCheck(5);
sleepCheck(8);
```

Comment: If it is a code test that fails, probably you have wrong error message - "Get some more shut eye!" vs "Get more some shut eye!"

Comment: ...`your function doesn't return "Get some more shut eye!"`  Check your `return` statements.  What do they return versus what the message is saying they should return?

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code. Instead the message is not what it is supposed to be.

Comment: return "Get some more shut eye!" instead of "Get more some shut eye!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var sleepCheck = function(numHours){
if (numHours >= 8) {
    return "You're getting plenty of sleep! Maybe even too much!";
} else {
    return "Get some more shut eye!";
}
};
```

You swapped "some" and "more" in your message... Get some coffee :-)

Comment: or get  more some shut eye the day before you code ;)